# ORA-01008: not all variables bound MVC application

Tags: c#, oracle

I am using VS2013 with Oracle 11g. I am trying to retrieve data from Oracle based on email.

This **works** because the email is hard-coded in the `WHERE` clause.

```
var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString); 
 connection.Open();
 OracleCommand myCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
 myCommand.BindByName = true;
 myCommand.CommandText = "select user_name FROM USERS WHERE E_MAIL= 'john@hotmail.com'";
```

WHen I try passing a variable it **fails**.

> *ORA-01008: not all variables bound*

```
var USER_EMAIL = "john@hotmail.com"; // NEW DECLARATION. 
 var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString); 
 connection.Open();
 OracleCommand myCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
 myCommand.BindByName = true;
 myCommand.CommandText = "select user_name FROM USERS WHERE E_MAIL= :USER_EMAIL";
```

How do I pass a variable into the select statement in oracle. ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
myCommand.CommandText = "select user_name FROM USERS WHERE E_MAIL= :email";
myCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("email", USER_EMAIL ));
```